# ros wiki package website incorrect

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my package 'moveit_simple_grasps' the ROS wiki seems to have the wrong website on the right side toolbox...

On: http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_simple_grasps

There is a link that says "moveit_simple_grasps website" but it links to

https://github.com/davetcoleman/simple_grasps/

When it should link to

https://github.com/davetcoleman/MOVEIT_simple_grasps/

According to `ros / rosdistro / indigo / distribution.yaml`

```
moveit_simple_grasps:
doc:
type: git
url: https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_simple_grasps.git
version: indigo-devel
release:
tags:
release: release/indigo/{package}/{version}
url: https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_simple_grasps-release.git
version: 1.2.0-1
source:
type: git
url: https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_simple_grasps.git
version: indigo-devel
status: developed
```

So where is it getting this incorrect information? Is there some hidden filter for the moveit keyword I don't know about?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193835/ros-wiki-package-website-incorrect/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is wrong in the package.xml:
https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_simple_grasps/blob/8210abc0236f99e73900a7a8709842ed78bd3a4a/package.xml

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-09-30**:
Ahh, I forgot about that location. Thanks!